# How to make selection with Pen tool in Pixelmator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections, pen-tool, pixelmator

I am new user in Pixelmator and I used to use Photoshop. Now, I would like to use Pen Tool in Pixelmator.
**In photoshop**, we use pen tool to cut things and then ***Ctrl+Enter*** to make a *selection*. 
**In pixelmator**, I cannot make selection and it automatically fills with color. All I want is just selection . 
Please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Pixelmator's Pen tool to make a selection per se, but you *can* use it to draw into a layer mask.  Does that work well enough for you?

Comment: I would like to know that how to make to get a selection by using a pen tool. I would like to get a selection dotted line.

Comment: You can't do this directly in Pixelmator—if you want a selection you'll have to create a new layer, draw with the pen tool into that, then use the brush selection tool to create a selection based on your pen shape.